# How to stream a video using the <video> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, video-streaming, lag

Can somebody please give a sample code?
How much lag will be there once I click on some time in case of HTML5 and some flash player like jw player?

Answer (score 0):

Look at

> http://html5video.org/

They have demos, info, etc.  Pretty much everything you need.